# Remove an action created by a Gravity Forms add-on

Tags: php, actions, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm using Gravity Forms User Registration add-on and need to remove the action that include the activate page.

In the add-on, the hook is called like this:

```
add_action( 'wp',        array( $this, 'maybe_activate_user' ) );
```

This is added inside a public function called `init()`, a method from `GF_User_Registration` class.

What I tried:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    remove_action('wp', ['GF_User_Registration', 'maybe_activate_user']);
});
```

Comment: The add-on uses `$this`, so you need to know and be able to access the object (i.e. class instance) in order to unhook the `maybe_activate_user` function. E.g. If they did `$object = new GF_User_Registration;`, then you would use `remove_action( 'wp', [ $object, 'maybe_activate_user' ] )`. But regarding how to find that class instance, you need to check the plugin forums/docs/codebase.

Comment: @SallyCJ the add-on use a static method called `get_instance()`. I tried run `$object = \GF_User_Registration::get_instance();` and then `remove_action('wp', [$object, 'maybe_activate_user']);` but didn't have success.

Comment: Try hooking on `init` with a greater number as the 3rd parameter, e.g. `add_action( 'init', <your function>, 20 )`. Or just hook your function on `wp` with a `1` priority - `add_action( 'wp', <your function>, 1 )`. That should work, if you're using the correct class instance.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ, add a greater number fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
add_action('init', function () {
    $object = \GF_User_Registration::get_instance();
    remove_action('wp', [$object, 'maybe_activate_user']);
}, 20);
```

Thanks SallyCJ for the tips!